# Error with AndroidManifest invalid package name (Capacitor)

Tags: android, capacitor

I'm new to Capacitor and I can't find much info on how to fix this issue. I tried making a new application and the error is still being thrown. I've looked through other posts and it appears as though I'm using the correct naming conventions. Could it be an issue with my Gradle or Android Studio install?

If it helps, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Here's the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.31hrive.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.31hrive.app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.31hrive.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The manifest was generated automatically by Capacitor, so I'm really not quite sure what the issue is.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: try to set `com.hrive31.app` instead of `com.31hrive.app`